# Using Bootstrap CSS with FuelUX

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fuelux

I'm wondering what the implications are of using the Bootstrap theme alongside FuelUX? 
What I'm after is big, bold fonts and something that looks like 
http://jsfiddle.net/adam_j_bradley/9phKW/ (which includes bootstrap.css)
 vs what I get if I remove the reference to bootstrap.css http://jsfiddle.net/adam_j_bradley/9phKW/2/

However, when I include the bootstrap CSS a lot of the other components break. Buttons are the wrong size (especially on forms, downright ugly!).

```
@import url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Any thoughts advice/tips warmly received.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle of what happens when the bootstrap.css is included? Additionally please consider the possibility that BS 3.2 is a new release and Fuel UX may not of caught up just yet.

Comment: Indeed, however you've stated what you want it to look like and what happens if you remove the bootstrap.css but not got a fiddle for what happens to YOUR bootstrap when Fuel UX is included

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 (JS, nor CSS) is not compatible with FuelUX 2. The enhanced FuelUX 3 (which is compatible with Bootstrap 3) is still in development and has been delayed due to internal timelines. You can view the development branch here: https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/tree/3.0.0-wip

And WIP documentation can be viewed here until the official release is posted on GitHub Pages:
http://getfuelux.com

UPDATE: Fuel UX was release August 2014 and can be found in the master branch and 3.x branch at https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/

Comment: That would explain it! I'll slot in the WIP branch and see what difference it makes. Thank you.